# SPOJ prime generator in PHP

Tags: php

I am getting `time limit exceeded` error while I submitted my solution.

```
<?php
$stdin = fopen('php://stdin', 'r');
$testcase = fgets($stdin);
$n=1;
while($n<=$testcase){   
    $start = fgets($stdin);
    $end=fgets($stdin);
    if($start==1) {
        $start=2;
    }
    for($i=$start;$i<$end;$i++){
        $flag=0;
        for($j=2;$j<$i;$j++){
            if($i%$j==0){
                $flag=1;
                break;
            }
        }
        if($flag==0){
            echo $i."\n";
        }
    }
    $n++;
}

fclose($stdin);
?>
```

Please help me out, I'm stuck with `time limit exceeded` error and please explain why I'm getting this error. In my local version it shows the correct answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the first for loop, instead for looping all the numbers, you can loop only the odd numbers since other than 2 all the even numbers can never be prime.

you can use `$i+=2` in first for loop. this could help you reduce some unnecessary looping.

Update 1:

Also inside second for loop, instead of finding modulo will all the numbers, you could just store the calculated prime numbers in an array and check whether the `$i % calculated prime numbers == 0` instead of `$i%$j`

Answer (score 1):

Your solution is too slow. Try a slightly modified Sieve of Eratosthenes. The modification should allow your sieve to work only in the [*start*, *end*] interval.